# auto increment ID database for asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, primary-key, auto-increment

I want show the auto increment on database to Create View. But on the textbox it is still '0'. I have already set the Id field to auto increment in database.

There's no error in my syntax but the id does not show.

This my View:

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-2">ID ATS</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.id_ats, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.id_ats, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

This my Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "id_ats, UniqueName, nama, prior_ex, start_date, end_date, coaching")] op_ats op_ats)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.op_ats.Add(op_ats);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(op_ats);
    }
```

```
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View(op);
    }
```

This is the image of my view:

[image]

This image is of my database:

[image]

But I am still confused with the controller.

Comment: auto increment  for id right

Comment: The view code looks good, but you'll need to show more code, like the model class, to further decipher what the issue might be.

Comment: You will need to expose your `HTTPGET` method. You will either have to make a db call in your `POST` to get the id and pass back into the view or do it in the `GET`. Make a db call of the item and get the id

Answer (score 0):

check Id properties
`Identity=false,
Identity seed=0,
Identity Increment=0.`
For this problem , set the Id as the Identity

Then check Id properties
`Identity=true,
Identity seed=1,
Identity Increment=1.
If identity=true`

Comment: i already set it all in databae. but the id on the view it's look 0 but when i save the recod the has auto increment

Comment: @Html.EditorFor(model => model.id_ats)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.id_ats, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

Comment: please try it and let me know

Comment: i try it and result still the same @ABCD

Comment: can you share your  httpget ,that you used to bind with model

Comment: @AyuAsriLestari Try using `@Html.TextBoxFor()` to display your value. If that does not work, then how are you getting this value: `op` when you are returning it in your `Create` action method: `return View(op);`